# Download JPEG files in batch mode keeping the path

Tags: php, batch-file, download, jpeg

I wish to download a lot of `jpeg`s keeping the original name and their paths.

Example: `http://www.somesite.org/path1/image1.jpg`, should be downloaded on `www.mysite.com/path1/image1.jpg` (and creating the `"path1"` directory if it does not exist)  This is repeated a lot of times, fetching the original download site from a field on a database.

Is it possible? Keep in mind that I can't use `cURL` nor `wget` since I am on a "limited" hosting service.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, first of all you have to find a method to get all download links. There are several ways to fetch data from a database, depending on what database it is (mysql, exel, textfile...)

Then you need to use ftp to upload these files into your database. Strip down the original link to the path (remove the www.somesite.org) and use your site + the path for storing.

This is very manageable, but we are not here to do all the thinking for you. Use google and try methods first, then come back if you are facing a **specific** problem.